# How is this font implemented to be engraved?

Tags: css

I'm looking at http://agilewebsolutions.com/support. As you can see, the text h2 and h3 all have an engraved effect giving it a 3d look. How is this accomplished? I couldn't dig it out of the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The h1 uses `text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #000000;` as it is a light text on a dark background.

The h2 uses `text-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;` which is the exact inverse of the one above. support.css (line 47)

However both look engraved because of the use of light text on dark bg + dark text on light bg.

Answer (score 2):

That is done with the CSS3 effect `text-shadow`. See [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/text-shadow/) for more info. IE still does not support most CSS3 properties though.